# scipy.optimize.curve_fit weird behaviour when trying to fit gaussian to data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have to fit a gaussian curve to some data. Here is the definition of my gaussian

```
def gaussian(x,sigma,mu):
  return np.array((1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*np.exp((-1/2)*np.power(((x-mu)/sigma),2)),dtype='float64')
```

Here is my test of my gaussian function definition

```
x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
y = gaussian(x,1,0)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

It produces an plot that behaves correctly,
[here is the image of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyJYL.png)

Now I have to fit this gaussian to some data.

```
x = np.array([ 8., 10., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22.,
       23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35.,
       36.],dtype='float64')
y = np.array([0.00220264, 0.00220264, 0.00220264, 0.00220264, 0.0154185 ,
       0.01321586, 0.02863436, 0.03303965, 0.06387665, 0.05506608,
       0.1123348 , 0.08590308, 0.0814978 , 0.0814978 , 0.04625551,
       0.06387665, 0.05726872, 0.05947137, 0.05726872, 0.02863436,
       0.03744493, 0.02863436, 0.01101322, 0.00881057, 0.01101322,
       0.00220264, 0.00881057],dtype='float64')
y_error = np.array([0.00220264, 0.00220264, 0.00220264, 0.00220264, 0.00582765,
       0.00539535, 0.00794174, 0.0085308 , 0.0118616 , 0.01101322,
       0.01573002, 0.0137555 , 0.01339816, 0.01339816, 0.01009378,
       0.0118616 , 0.01123132, 0.01144527, 0.01123132, 0.00794174,
       0.00908173, 0.00794174, 0.00492526, 0.00440529, 0.00492526,
       0.00220264, 0.00440529],dtype='float64')
```

Plotting this data using

```
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=y_error,fmt='.')
```

yields the following [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQNKI.png)

now when I try to fit some data using scipy.optimize.curve_fit
I get

```
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(gaussian,x,y,sigma=y_error,absolute_sigma=True)
plt.plot(x,gaussian(x,*popt)) # plotting the gaussian
```

This produces this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnUvj.png), superimposed on the previous plot of my original data. This is not a bell curve at all. Why is it behaving this way? I checked for stuff that was wrong with my data and couldn't find anything strange. All the arrays passed into curve fit are float64, my gaussian function can accept a np.array of 'float64' and output an array of the same type. I'm perplexed as to what can go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, the solution was just to supply a good initial guess on the mean by passing p0=[sigma_guess,mean_guess] as a parameter to curve_fit(). [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Mce.png) is the result. For context (I was trying to fit occurrence vs counts per sampling interval measured by a Geiger counter in the presence of a radioactive source, so computing an estimate for the mean was easy).

Comment: Hi, so I guess the have the original statistics and created the histogramm by binning. In that case you're right: you can get mean and standard deviation directly from your data. using e.g. `numpy.mean()` and `numpy.std()`

Comment: Also note that you can then directly fit your data with `scipy.stats.norm.fit()` and get the gaussian via `scipy.stats.norm.pdf()`